# Authenticating with Adwords Googleads without local storage

Tags: django, python-3.x, google-ads-api, django-1.9

So having trouble finding documentation or tutorials on this. We're at the starts of a project using Python (Django) and are putting together a couple of proof-of-concept functions.

I'm trying to use the googleads python library to authenticate with the adwords api. Currently though, I can only find examples that pull the adwords credentials from local storage:

> adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

The problem is, we'll be storing api keys and the likes in the database as multiple adwords managers may be utilizing the tool. As such, it's not ideal to store the credentials in a static file (it looks like the credentials for loadfromstorage are stored in a yaml file, though I'm having a bit of trouble finding details even on that).

Does anyone have a good example of setting up an adwords client "on the fly", knowing the api key and generating other items as needed.

Let me know y'alls thoughts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the long version is here [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/tree/master/googleads)

tl;dr

```
#in case you need proxy to access the internet
prxx = common.ProxyConfig.Proxy(YOUR_PROXY_HOST, YOUR_PROXY_PORT )
proxy_config = common.ProxyConfig(http_proxy=prxx,https_proxy=prxx,disable_certificate_validation=True)

#init oauth refresh token client
oauth_client = oauth2.GoogleRefreshTokenClient(client_id=YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID, client_secret=YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,refresh_token=YOUR_GOOGLE_REFRESH_TOKEN, proxy_config=proxy_config )

#adwords client
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient(YOUR_DEVELOPER_TOKEN,oauth_client, user_agent=YOUR_USER_AGENT, client_customer_id=YOUR_CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID, proxy_config=proxy_config)
```